# Get ViewBag Data after $.ajax post success c# .net razor

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm posting data with ajax and it's successfully posted. At the controller side I'm filling a ViewBag with data posted but i'm having a problem getting data from ViewBag.

Here's Ajax Code:

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../Home/getExistUsersFromJSON',
            data: JSON.stringify({ jsonString: JSON.stringify(array) }),
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function () {
                // Alert that it was succesful!
                var jsonList = '@Html.Raw(Json.Convert(ViewBag.newUsers))';
                var jsList = JSON.parse(jsonList);
                bootbox.dialog({
                    message: jsList,
                    title: "Utilisateurs",
                    buttons: {
                        success: {
                            label: "Success!",
                            className: "btn-success"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

And this is the controller side

```
 [ActionName("getExistUsersFromJSON")]
    public void getExistUsersFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {

        IList<newUser> ctm =
      new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<newUser>>(jsonString);
        ViewBag.newUsers = ctm.ToList();

    }
```

Comment: Why are you passing a JSON object that just contains another JSON string? You should pass the array directly.

Comment: When I pass the array directly I get an error of Bad request. this is the only way that pass the JSON array to the controller

Comment: Did you read the error message?  You probably have the wrong parameters in your action.

Comment: If it was the case i'll get an error when i fill my IList<newUser> with JSON data passed in jsonString

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag` is just an object that gets passed to the view when you render the page.

It doesn't make any sense to use that with AJAX; your server-side Razor code runs on initial server render only.

You need to server JSON as the response (using `Json()`).

Comment: Can you explain more how to use using Json() to get data from controller on ajax complete and show them in the view